# Checking for undefined variables in a function php

Tags: php

So I've been trying to devise a function that will `echo` a session variable only if it is set, so that it wont create the 'Notice' about an undefined variable. I am aware that one could use:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['i'])){ echo $_SESSION['i'];}
```

But it starts to get a bit messy when there are loads (As you may have guessed, it's for bringing data back into a form ... For whatever reason). Some of my values are also only required to be echoed back if it equals something, echo something else which makes it even more messy:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['i'])){if($_SESSION['i']=='value'){ echo 'Something';}}
```

So to try and be lazy, and tidy things up, I have tried making these functions:

```
function ifsetecho($variable) {
    if(!empty($variable)) {
        echo $variable;
    }
}

function ifseteqecho($variable,$eq,$output) {
    if(isset($variable)) {
        if($variable==$eq) {
            echo $output;
        }
    }
}
```

Which wont work, because for it to go through the function, the variable has to be declared ...

Has anyone found a way to make something similar to this work?

Comment: It would be nice to know why someone down voted this :D

Answer (score 0):

You may use variable variables:

```
$cat = "beautiful";
$dog = "lovely";

function ifsetecho($variable) {
    global $$variable;
    if(!empty($$variable)){
        echo $$variable;
    }
}

ifsetecho("cat");
echo "<br/>";
ifsetecho("dog");
echo "<br/>";
ifsetecho("elephant");
```

---

**UPDATE:** With a rather complex code I’ve managed to meet your requirements:

```
session_start();
$cat = "beautiful";
$dog = "lovely";
$_SESSION['person']['fname'] = "Irene";

function ifsetecho($variable){
    $pattern = "/([_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]+)".str_repeat("(?:\\['([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)'\\])?", 6)."/";
    if(preg_match($pattern, $variable, $matches)){
        global ${$matches[1]};
        if(empty(${$matches[1]})){
            return false;
        }
        $plush = ${$matches[1]};
        for($i = 2; $i < sizeof($matches); $i++){
            if(empty($plush[$matches[$i]])){
                return false;
            }
            $plush = $plush[$matches[$i]];
        }
        echo $plush;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

ifsetecho("cat");
echo "<br/>";
ifsetecho("dog");
echo "<br/>";
ifsetecho("elephant");
echo "<br/>";
ifsetecho("_SESSION['person']['fname']");
echo "<br/>";
ifsetecho("_SESSION['person']['uname']");
echo "<br/>";
```

Comment: This is utterly pointless. $cat and $dog will NOT in in the scope of that function, so not only is this code useless, it's also going to be spitting out undefined variable warnings all over the place.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for session variables :(

Comment: What I tried was: `ifsetecho("_SESSION['person']['fname']")`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can achieve this with a foreach?

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $variable)
 {function ifseteqecho($variable,$eq,$output) {
    if($variable==$eq) {
        echo $output;
    }
    else echo $variable;
  }
}
```

now this will all check for the same `$eq`, but with an array of corresponding `$eq` to `$variables`:

```
$equiv = array
 ('1'=>'foo',
  'blue'=>'bar',);
```

you can check them all:

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $variable)
 {function ifseteqecho($variable,$equiv) {
    if(isset($equiv[$variable])) {
      echo $equiv[$variable];
    }
    else {
      echo $variable;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is unfortunately not what I'm after, as I need to have the variables echo'd in specific places, rather than just echo everything if it is set.

Comment: then why want a global solution if it's to be used in specific places? moreover, you can redirect the output to be returned instead of being ecoed right away, letting you a way to manage where it will go

Comment: Basically, I just wanted a function that could just be placed anywhere that checks if the variable is set, and then echoes it if it is. For the sole reason of tidying up code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?, you could extend it to fit your precise needs...

```
function echoIfSet($varName, array $fromArray=null){
   if(isset($fromArray)){
      if(isset($fromArray[$varName])&&!empty($fromArray[$varName])){
          echo $fromArray[$varName];
      }
   }elseif(isset($$varName)&&!empty($$varName)){
      echo $$varName;
   }
}
```